# Why modifies only one aggregate instance per transaction?

Tags: domain-driven-design

I'm reading Vernon's article [Effective Aggregate Design](http://dddcommunity.org/wp-content/uploads/files/pdf_articles/Vernon_2011_1.pdf). And I have a question about why modifies only one aggregate instance per transaction?

Let's take an example, consider a Warehouse invertory management story.

**Inventory** represents an item with quantity in a warehouse. 5 [Implementing Domain Driven Design](https://vaughnvernon.co/?page_id=168) books in Shanghai warehouse for instance.

**Entry** represents a log about an in/out operation on an **Inventory**. Entering 2 [Implementing Domain Driven Design](https://vaughnvernon.co/?page_id=168) books in Shanghai warehouse for instance.

An **Inventory**'s quantity need to be changed if an **Entry** is submitted.

It easily comes to my mind, this is an invarient could be implemented by transactional consistency.

***Solution A***: Using one Aggregate and cluster **Entry** into **Inventory**.

```
public class Inventory implements Aggregate<Inventory> {
     private InventoryIdentity id;
     private Sku sku;
     private int quantity;
     private List<Entry> entries;

     public void add(Entry entry) {
         this.quantity += entry.getQuantity();
         this.entries.add(entry);
     }
}

public class Entry implements LocalEntity<Entry> {
    private int quantity;
    // some other attributes such as whenSubmitted
}

public class TransactionalInventoryAdminService impelments InventoryAdminService, ApplicationService {

     @Override
     @Transactional
     public void handle(InventoryIdentity inventoryId, int entryQuantity, ...other entry attributes)
         Inventory inventory = inventoryRepository.findBy(inventoryId);
         Entry entry = inventory.newEntry(entryQuantity, ..);   
         inventory.add(entry);
         inventoryRepository.store(inventory);
     }
}
```

***Solution B***: Using seperate Aggregate for **Inventory** and **Entry**.

```
public class Inventory implements Aggregate<Inventory> {
     private InventoryIdentity id;
     private Sku sku;
     private int quantity;

     public void add(int quantity) {
         this.quantity += quantity;
     }
}

public class Entry implements LocalEntity<Entry> {
    private Inventory inventory;
    private int quantity;
    private boolean handled = false;
    // some other attributes such as whenSubmitted

    public void handle() {
        if (handled) {
            throw .....
        } else {
            this.inverntory.add(quantity);
            this.handled = true;
        }
    }     
}

public class TransactionalInventoryAdminService impelments InventoryAdminService, ApplicationService {

     @Override
     @Transactional
     public void handle(InventoryIdentity inventoryId, int entryQuantity, ...other entry attributes)
         Inventory inventory = inventoryRepository.findBy(inventoryId);
         Entry entry = inventory.newEntry(entryQuantity, ..);   
         entry.handle();
         inventoryRepository.store(inventory);
         entryRepository.store(entry);
     }
}
```

Both A and B are feasible, but solution B is kind of inelegant for leaving inadvertent oppertunity to invoke **Inventory**.add(quantity) without **Entry** involved. **Is this what the rule (Modifies only one aggregate instance per transaction) tries to point out for me? I'm confused mostly why we should modify only one aggregate in a transaction, what goes wrong if we don't.**

***Update1 start***

Is it intend to alleviate concurrency problems (with another rule of "make smaller aggregates")? For example, **Entry** is an Aggregate with  relatively low contention and **Inventory** is one with relatively high contetion (assuming that multiple user could manipulate one **Inventory**), it causes unnecessary concurrency failure if I modify them both in a transaction .

***Update1 end***

Some further problems need to be addressed if I adopt solution A:

1.What if there are many **Entry** s for an **Inventory** and I need a paged query UI? How to implement a paged query using Collections? One way is to load all **Entry** s and picks what the page need, the other way is InventoryRepository.findEntriesBy(invoiceId, paging), but this seems to break the rule of get an local entity only by get it's aggreate then navigate the object graph.

2.What if there are too many **Entry** s for an **Inventory** and I have to load all of them when add an new **Entry**?

I know these questions stem from lacking full understanding. So any idea is welcome, thanks in advance.

Comment: I think that this approach also mitigates the chance that a dead lock can occur http://stackoverflow.com/questions/735894/database-deadlocks

Answer (score 15):

Rule of thumb is to keep your aggregates small, since you want to avoid transactional failures due to concurrency. And why would we make the memory footprint big if it shouldn't be?

So, solution A is not optimal. Big aggregates often introduce problems that easily can be avoided.

It's true that another rule of thumb is to only change one aggregate in one transaction. If you make Entry it's own aggregate, you can make the inventory's quantity eventual consistent, meaning the Entry aggregate could raise an event to which the inventory is subscribed. This way you're only changing one aggregate per transaction.

```
public class Entry {
    public Entry(InventoryId inventoryId, int quantity) {
         DomainEvents.Raise(new EntryAdded(inventoryId, quantity))
    }
}
```

If you don't feel comfortable with eventual consistency, you can still keep the aggregates separate, but modify them both in one transaction for now - until you're feeling the pain, using an encapsulating domain service. Another option is to keep the domain events in process, so that they're also committed in a single transaction.

```
 public class InventoryService {
     public void AddEntryToInventory(Entry entry) {
          // Modify Inventory quantity
          // Add Entry
     }
 }
```

Comment: +1 Thank you for the reply. I'm confused mostly why we should modify only one aggregate in a transaction, what goes wrong if we don't.

Comment: Your reminding "Rule of thumb is to keep your aggregates small" gave me a clue, see my question updated.

Comment: I had to Google Translate 'to alleviate' ;) But in response to your update: yes.

Comment: :) I learned this word in Enterprise Integration Pattern. "Some tools can help alleviate this problem" if I'm not mistaken. I'm learning English as well.

Comment: "Another option is to keep the domain events in process, so that they're also committed in a single transaction." Ok, but this still breaks the law of modifying one aggregate per transaction, or I don't get your clue @JefClaes ?

Comment: You're right, but once you're seeing those transactional failures in production, you might have an incentive to bite the bullet and move them out  process.

Comment: Can you add a more detailed explanation of _why_ this "one aggregate per transaction" rule of thumb exists? You seem to hint that this has to do with "transactional failures in production", but I'm eager to know exactly what kind of failures we are likely to encounter. And whether they exceed the potential risks of eventual consistency (e.g. selling an item twice because the inventory was consistent _too late_).

Comment: @Timo Let's say I modify the description of a product while someone is buying it. Do I really want to say to my customer "Oops, your order failed, because we just changed the description of the product you're trying to buy."? We could use pessimistic concurrency strategies, but then you might have a user waiting 2 seconds for his order to go through because I'm modifying the product.Usually smaller aggregates means less contention on a resource, thus less transient failures.

Comment: @Timo In mature systems a business process that handles these cases is usually in place. An inventory will never be truly consistent. You think you can still sell the last vase in your inventory, while in reality someone just dropped it 2 minutes ago, moving things in the warehouse.

Comment: @JefClaes Interesting point about true consistency - though keep in mind that there are many systems that are purely digital and do not involve such analog cases. About your example on multiple aggregates per transaction: I'm looking for a more realistic one. Surely the purchase does not alter the product definition. I have seen many instances where a transaction inserts one aggregate and updates another, where there was simply no realistic scenario of the latter getting a conflicting update from another process. So although this _can_ be an issue in some situations, often it's not.

Answer (score 1):

One of the reason you should avoid modifying multiple aggregates in single transaction is that each aggregate may be stored in different db storage and may require some specific transaction handling or impose all the difficulty of managing distributed transactions (two-phase commit etc).

The better approach is eventual consistency along with events and saga pattern.

See also: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/356106/ddd-why-is-it-a-bad-practice-to-update-multiple-aggregate-roots-per-transaction