# Hibernate \ JPA - order database updates (table orders)

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, orm

How do I set the ORM (JPA or hibernate) to order the database updates? I've heard its a very good mitigation practice to avoid deadlock.

Best,

Comment: Do you have any reference to an online article describing that ordering practice?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/735963/1103894

Comment: The practice is OK (eg if two processes have to update both rows with IDs 1000 and 5000 at the same time, if both do it in ID order there's no deadlock).  However, Hibernate (nor anything else I know) Will not do it for you.  Updates will always be performed in the order you specify them.  You cannot (through hibernate or anything else) constrain the order of a multi-row UPDATE statement.  Usually for single-row updates it's more trouble than its worth.